# how can I detect wifi networks without connecting to them on IOS&Android with Unity?

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine

for example, I have an int type variable and it counts the detected wifi networks while my app is running. So how can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.

I'm pretty sure iOS doesn't have an API that allows you to detect the wifi networks.

You can get information related to the connectivity of a device and the type of connectivity (3G, 4G, wifi), but that's pretty much what you can do.

I don't know about Android, but I doubt is possible.

That being said I don't know of any Unity API that allows you to do that and that's probably because the native part doesn't have support for it anyway.